# Dealing with Options in Scala Play Template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am trying reference things of type option in my Scala Play template. I've been trying to use this resource: http://www.playframework.com/modules/scala-0.9/templates

This is how I am trying to reference a field in the case class:

```
@{optionalobject ?. field}
```

and it is not working, this is the error I am getting:

```
';' expected but '.' found.
```

I am unsure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@optionalobject.map(o => o.field).getOrElse("default string if optionalobject is None")
```

Answer (score 25):

For slightly nicer formatting that can span many lines (if you need to):

```
@optionalObject match {
  case Some(o) => {
    @o.field
  }
  case None => {
    No field text/html/whatever
  }
}
```

Or if you don't want to display anything if the field isn't defined:

```
@for(o <- optionalObject) {
  @o.field
}
```

Comment: That second code snippet for the _display nothing if the field isn't defined_ use case is lovely. I keep on glossing over the fact that ``Option`` is a collection type, allowing you to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your tags you are using a Play 2.x variant, but you are referencing documentation from a module meant for Play 1.x.

Assuming your types match, I believe what you are looking for is something like:

```
@optionalobject.getOrElse(field)
```

Comment: This is not working. It is saying that the field does not exist. However, it must exist. When just output the case class it shows all of the fields of the case class.

Comment: @Lilluda5 Edit your question and show more of your code. How are you declaring `optionalobject` and `field`?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using map, syntax I prefer for mixing up with HTML

```
@pagination.next.map { next =>
  <a href="@Routes.paginated(next)">
    @HtmlFormat.escape("Next >>>")
  </a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might be convenient to write a short helper when dealing with `Option` to declutter the template code:

```
  // Helper object is defined in some file Helper.scala
  object Helper {
    def maybeAttribute[T](attrName:String, maybeValue:Option[String]) = 
       maybeValue.fold("") { value => 
         Html(attrName + "=" + value).toString()
       }
  }
```

Then the template can use this helper method directly like

```
  // some view.scala.html file
  <div @Helper.maybeAttribute("id",maybeId)>
  </div>
```